# Ionic - InAppBrowser keep opening system external web browser not in-app one

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native, inappbrowser, ngx-bootstrap

In Ionic App page (`ionic serve`'s localhost:8100 page), the developer console logged the warning

> Native: InAppBrowser is not installed or you are running on a browser. Falling back to window.open.

What happened in web browser is actually also happened when I tested it on the device (`ionic cap run android`). The website was opened on device's default external web browser instead of the app's "in-app" web browser. I think because the `InAppBrowser` was never installed to the device during the build. But I have no idea why.

Below is the most simplified workable version of my codes. Feel free to ask if more needed.

---

main.ts

```
if (environment.production) enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(App).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

---

app.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [Comp],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule, BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), Routing
  ],
  providers: [
    InAppBrowser, { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [Comp]
})
export class App {}
```

---

routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./home').then(m => m.Home) }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Routing {}
```

---

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root', templateUrl: 'component.html', styleUrls: ['component.scss'],
})
export class Comp {}
```

---

home.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, FormsModule, IonicModule, RouterModule.forChild([{path: '', component: Page}])
  ],
  declarations: [Page]
})
export class Home {}
```

---

page.ts

```
export class Page{

  constructor(private iab : InAppBrowser, private platform : Platform) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.iab.create(URL, _blank); //tried _self too. not working
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to pass options to your function.

Comment: `this.iab.create(url, '_blank', options);` use this.

Comment: ok thank you for your reply. i'll take a look

Comment: sorry. i can't find any option available to force the app to either open the page in inappbrowser or at least notice if it wasn't installed. i tried with both _self and _blank. neither is working

Comment: Did you install it first? I think the device is still not ready to use the plugin, inside the `app.component.ts` try `this.platform.ready().then(() => {this.iab.create("url_here", _blank);});`

Comment: @PeterHaddad thanks for your reply. have tried with button prevly. not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to install the plugin before installing the package. My apologize for the lack of information.

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

But yet the inconvenience should be handled better. Still wonder why missing plugin doesn't regarded as an error.